# Weapon Models in Overwatch Dissapearing at Start of Game

Tags: overwatch

When I first join a game in Overwatch my weapon seems to be invisible. In addition, for the first few seconds my character and my teammates are invisible too. The problem usually fixes itself around 20 seconds in, but it gets very annoying when I join a game that is in-progress; my teammates are invisible, the enemy is invisible and I end up dying the moment I run out of the spawn room.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: This is almost certainly done to load you in as fast as possible.  I'm not sure there's a solution other than "get a faster computer".  Is there a setting for lowering the texture resolution?

Comment: Did you try to update your graphic card drivers ? It might help, even if I think that this problem is strongly related to latency.

Comment: Get a better HDD, won't matter if you got a top class graphic card if your hard drive cannot load the textures fast enough for them to be displayed when you enter the game

Comment: Everyone is assuming that you're playing on PC. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, I'm playing on PC. I also have an SSD so I almost think that its I load in faster than I'm supposed too. I updated my graphics driver and checked the solutions on the answer. I load the models slightly faster now. Thanks everyone.

Comment: I've noticed this same issue while playing on the PS4, so it may not be *completely* a PC issue. There is definitely something Blizzard needs to fix on their side.

Comment: This is a year late, but it's a known issue because Overwatch delays loading assets until the first time they're used.  Hence, things like character models and weapons aren't visible until you're in your first game.  On a side note, Team Fortress 2 had a similar problem when Valve modified it to do the same thing in... 2013?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution 1 : Lower the settings in order to make loadtime faster.

Solution 2 : Tweak your computer to optimize its performance. Before playing, make sure every other application is closed (Skype, Steam, WebBrowser, etc ...), make sure there's nothing updating, no antivirus scanning ...

Solution 3 : Get a better computer in order to make loadtime faster.